# How do i record a user information such as email in RubyOnRails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am creating a post request for Forgot Password request. So I generated a controller using:

```
rake generate controller post forgot_password
```

Now since I want to record a user email on my form so defined them as follows:

```
def forgot_password
  @password = params[:forgot_password]
  if @password  
    then @record = Email.create({:email => @email})
  end        
end
```

Is it correct?

I am very new to ruby on rails.

What are your views in doing this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an easier way to do this is by using the devise gem. it comes with all of the features you will need for password reset, change, unlocking account and so on... try reading reading its documentation, you will get it. 
luck!

Comment: But if this is a very specific case to code. How can I achieve it?

Comment: well, Code is not included in my response, but Devise itself is a lot to include in here. take a look a this link: [https://github.com/plataformatec/devise]  follow the documentation on how to install it. once installed, it will generate all of the routes for both sign in, sign out, reset password. it will  generate forms for signup, signin on which you will see a link to reset the password.  I know codes are not included here, but give it a little bit of your time.  luck!